# Jsp loads only half way

Tags: java, jsp, jboss5.x

I have an application, which was working fine in production. But suddenly two of the jsp pages stopped working, one of them loads only half and other does not load at all.

Problem here is,

> I am unable to replicate this scenario in development environment. I
>   have taken the production dump of data and production code, but still
>   unable to create production scenario, in development everything is
>   working fine. In production I am using **jboss 5**.

Can you please help me figure out what the problem is. As this happened all of a sudden I do not feel that it is code error, it may be something related to server configuration or memory setup. It also cannot be data problem, as I have taken production dump and tested in development, everything works fine.

Please provide me some solution or way to proceed to solution.

Comment: Did you try to deploy again? Maybe something went wrong with the deployment.

Comment: *"Please provide me ...a  way to proceed to solution."* - Look at the log files.

Comment: Yes, I did deploy. But no configurations changed. Everything else is working fine apart from these pages. Even after deployment, it worked for few days and later it stopped.